# Is there any way to navigate to module without full app reload #Angular6?

Tags: angular6, angular7-router

"One module to second module Navigation without whole app reload"

I have used 'Window.open' to switch module but it reloads the whole app.I have tried another method this.router.navigate & navigateByUrl it works but according to new module sidebar component does not load it remains same.

//It reloads the whole app 
    `window.open("/mfg","_self")`

//This method navigates to new module without reload but its sidebar does not load 
    `this._router.navigate(["/mfg"])`

When i click on any module from side bar it should move to this module without reloading whole app and its sidebar component must be update according to module.

Comment: With limited knowledge of what you're trying to achieve. I would suggest looking into some sort of state

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly Sir you're right but if some one has already faced this problem , he will understand.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Wow, so it's like one of those `hit 'post your answer' if you can relate` kind of a question!